# Why Can't EigensCount Be Greater Than TrainingImagesCount-1 [EigenObjectRecognizer]

Tags: opencv, emgucv, face-recognition, eigen

http://www.cognotics.com/opencv/servo_2007_series/part_5/fig_6_thumb.png

Can anyone explain why nEgiens must not be over nTrainFace-1 on the picture above?

I am using EmguCv. When nEgiens and nTrainFace are equals, last eigen image is returned blank (black).
However, on emgucv implementation:

```
`if (termCrit.max_iter <= 0 || termCrit.max_iter > trainingImages.Length)
    termCrit.max_iter = trainingImages.Length;`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mathematical constriction:

> The rank of the covariance matrix is limited by the number of training examples: if there are N training examples, there will be at most N-1 eigenvectors with non-zero eigenvalues.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface#Computing_the_eigenvectors

Comment: I thought N eigenvectors doesn't include the zero vector, but it does. Thank you...